# Get parent and grandparent from self referencing table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I have a `offices` table that is self referencing

```
id   name  parent_id
---------------------
1     A       0
2     B       1
3     C       2
4     D       3
```

the expected output :

```
child       - grandparent
parent      - grandparent
grandparent - grandparent
```

for more visualization

```
id    name    expected_name
---------------------------
4      D         B
3      C         B
2      B         B
```

My code:

```
SELECT child.id,child.name,grand.name
FROM offices AS child
JOIN offices AS parent ON child.parent_office_id = parent.id
JOIN offices AS grand  ON grand.id = parent.parent_office_id
WHERE child.id=4
```

It is giving me only child-grandparent result.I need other two relations too.How can I achieve this?

Comment: For what you have coded, just use `SELECT child.id, child.name, parent.id, parent.name, grandparent.id, grandparent.name FROM...` (For a different layout of the same result, please specify if this is MySQL 5.x or MySQL 8)

Comment: Also, what should the result be if there is no grandparent in the data? For example; `WHERE child.id = 2`?

Comment: It is MySQL 8.Your suggestion will output one row.right?I need three rows.

Comment: @MatBailie it is static data.

Comment: What does "it's static data" mean?

Comment: @MatBailie initial `id` will have a grandparent always.query will start from `child.id=4`

Comment: Then hard code the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT child.id  cid, child.name  cname, 
                     parent.id pid, parent.name pname, 
                     grand.id  gid, grand.name  gname
              FROM offices AS child
              JOIN offices AS parent ON child.parent_id = parent.id
              JOIN offices AS grand  ON parent.parent_id = grand.id 
              WHERE child.id = 4 )
SELECT cid id, cname name, gname expected_name FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT pid, pname, gname FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT gid, gname, gname FROM cte
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77a59b2f6b8604e042754f6986b9a24b

Comment: Should be worth noting that this code (as does the Op's) returns nothing if there is no grandparent.

Comment: @MatBailie That's true. But OP must define does this situation is possible (maybe initial `id` will have grandparent always) and what output is needed in such case.

Comment: I'd also add a `depth` column, so the results can be deterministically sorted, rather than relying on implicit row positioning.

Comment: Only a cyclic data set can Always have a grandparent. Trees have leaves and roots.  (`WHERE child.id = 2` returns nothing in the OP's demo set.)

Comment: @MatBailie And again - OP must tell about this. Anycase he can use my query as a pattern and build his own query which takes all these points into account.

Comment: Thus, my comment "worth Noting that..." If code exhibits a particular behaviour for an ambiguous scenario, that behaviour should be noted.

Comment: @MatBailie The base of the solution is UNION ALL. This seems to be the only useful way  for to obtain 3 output rows for one source row (of course a bunch of CASEs can be used, but I doubt that this is reasonable). All another details are minor. I think...